Why are Tailwind CSS classes not working with Material UI <Button>?
I'm attempting to make a circular button with a Material UI icon, but my various efforts have failed to produce the desired shape. I am creating a React.js component for my project.
Version Detail :
node - 20.16.0
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
"@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.2",
"@mui/material": "^6.1.2",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.1.2",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"react-icons": "^5.3.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
"react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
"styled-components": "^6.1.13"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
"@types/react": "^18.3.10",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
"eslint": "^9.11.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
"globals": "^15.9.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.47",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
"vite": "^5.4.8"
}
Here are different approach I tried:
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import MenuOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MenuOpen';


/*----- Approach 1 ---------*/

<Button className='w-10 h-10 rounded-full'><MenuOpenIcon/></Button>


/*----- Approach 2 ---------*/

<Button
  sx={{
    width: '2.5rem',
    height: '2.5rem',  
    borderRadius: '9999px',
  }}
>
  <MenuOpenIcon />
</Button>


/*------ Approach 3 -------*/

import { styled } from '@mui/system';

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`@apply w-10 h-10 rounded-full;`;


<StyledButton><MenuOpenIcon /></StyledButton>


<Button className='w-10 h-10 rounded-full'><MenuOpenIcon/></Button>

update your code with min with class as follows
<Button className='w-10 h-10 rounded-full min-w-10'><MenuOpenIcon/></Button>

to get perfect circle around your button, also you can increase or decrease size of icons by using font size class as follows
<Button className='w-10 h-10 rounded-full min-w-10'><MenuOpenIcon fontSize='medium'/></Button>

hope it will resolve your issue.

Checkout the MUI documentation when working with Tailwind CSS and MUI.
Documentation
If you want to work with Tailwind CSS, you can set the precedence of more by setting the important option as true in tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}



But it is not a good practice to work with more than one CSS framework.


Maybe you could try Shadcn/ui. Material UI is often preferred by styled-component developers, but Shadcn/ui is based on Tailwind CSS and has a lot of great extends by social like these: awesome-shadcn-ui
."
